# How to filter events with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, events, filter

I am new to jQuery . 
I am trying to solve a problem I have with jQuery.

The application I am developing has a Canvas and I want to filter out events going into it.

The way I tried to do this was put a div tag over the canvas. If event is allowed trigger it on the canvas.

```
#overlay {
      position: fixed; /* Sit on top of the page content */
      display: block; /* Hidden by default */
      width: 100%; /* Full width (cover the whole page) */
      height: 100%; /* Full height (cover the whole page) */
      top: 0; 
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); /* Black background with opacity */
      z-index: 200;

    }


<div id="overlay"> </div> 
<canvas id="GameCanvas" oncontextmenu="event.preventDefault()" tabindex="0"></canvas>
```

The events I want to prevent is F11 (fullscreen) and Zoom.
I don't want them to be handled by the canvas, because they don't work if canvas start to handle it. They need to be handled by the web page.

I got both of them working by capturing keyboard events

```
$(document).on(
    {
        keydown:eventKey,
        keyup:eventKey,
    });

function eventKey(e)
{
    if (!
        (
        // don't allow zoom with ctrl +/-
        ((e.which == 107 || e.which == 109 || e.which == 96) && e.ctrlKey) 
        || 
        // F11 fullscreen
        (e.which == 122)
        )
        )
    {
        // don't allow zoom with ctrl +/-
        $("GameCanvas").trigger(e);
    }   
}
```

The problem I have is I don't know how to handle mouse events. 
I want to prevent canvas from handling Ctrl + mouse scroll (zoom) and allow it to handle all other events.

i trigger events like this

```
$(document).on(
    {
        mousedown:mouseEvent,
        mouseup:mouseEvent,
        click:mouseEvent,
    }); 

    function mouseEvent(e)
    {
        $('GameCanvas').trigger(e);
    }
```

But for some reason the canvas does not seems to receive the events.

Can someone explain how to do this?

Or is there a better way of handling this?

Comment: There is a $(window).on('wheel', function(event) option i.e.https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onwheel.asp

Comment: @mkane this does the trick.
but how do i fire other mouse events into the canvas ?

Comment: Create an event i.e. var myEvent = jQuery.Event('mousedown', {.... and then simply fire it where desired i.e. $(selector).trigger(myEvent)